# Where can I find slide and film holders for the Minolta Dimage Scan Multi Pro multi-format scanner?

Tags: scanner

I need slide and film holders (FH-P1, SH-P1) for the Minolta Dimage Scan Multi PRO multi-format scanner.  I checked ebay and did some google searching, but I didn't find anything.  Does anyone have suggestions where this type of thing could be found?

Comment: A related (but, unfortunately, not necessarily very helpful) article from just the other day: http://theonlinephotographer.typepad.com/the_online_photographer/2011/12/burning-our-bridges.html

Answer (score 3):

I doubt most people owning such a scanner are willing to part with the parts, as they haven't been in production for a long time and supplier stocks will have depleted years ago (if they could still be found after all the Minolta/Konica/Sony mergers).
Your best bet may be to look for someone trying to sell a scanner complete with the parts, either on eBay, Craigslist, etc. etc., or through stores dealing in used camera and/or computer equipment.